# How does Pygame know what is layer 1 (background) vs the sprites displayed on the screen?

Tags: python, pygame

My teacher was looking over my code today and wanted me to explain to him why I could use

```py
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500
PLAYER, SIZE = 34, 34
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))

Player_1 = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('skins', 'player.png')), (PLAYER,SIZE))
P1 = pygame.transform.rotate(Player_1, 270)
Player_2 = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('skins', 'enemy.png')), (PLAYER,SIZE))
P2 = pygame.transform.rotate(Player_2, 270)
SKY = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('skins', 'bg.png')), (WIDTH,HEIGHT))
#this will search our folder 'skins' for the file 'bg' to make our background
BULLET_SPEED = 5
BULLET_NUMBER = 5

BULLET_FIRE_SOUND = pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join('soundEffects', 'tiro.wav'))
BULLET_DAMAGE_SOUND = pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join('soundEffects', 'batida.wav'))


def draw(yellow, blue, yellow_bullets, blue_bullets, yellow_health, blue_health):
    WIN.blit(SKY, (0,0)) 
    pygame.draw.rect(WIN, WHITE, MID_BORDER)
    WIN.blit(P1, (yellow.x, yellow.y))
    WIN.blit(P2, (blue.x, blue.y))
    #pygame starts tracking at the top left with 0,0
    for bullet in blue_bullets:
        pygame.draw.rect(WIN, BLUE, bullet)
    for bullet in yellow_bullets:
        pygame.draw.rect(WIN, YELLOW, bullet)
    yellow_health_txt = HEALTH_FONT.render("Health: " + str(yellow_health), 1, WHITE)
    blue_health_txt = HEALTH_FONT.render("Health: " + str(blue_health), 1, WHITE)
    WIN.blit(yellow_health_txt,(10,10))
    WIN.blit(blue_health_txt,(WIDTH - blue_health_txt.get_width() - 10, 10))


    pygame.display.update()
```

and pygame knew to make the `bg.png` file the background and the `player/enemy.png` in the foreground.

I explained that maybe it was due to `bg.png` taking the `HEIGHT` and `WIDTH` arg therefore stretching the whole screen, but almost immediately I saw a flaw in this logic as `player/enemy.png` could easily be behind the `bg.png` and be hidden completely.

Obviously it's not taking the order I declare them as I declare `bg.png` last.

So is there any way to understand the logic behind how pygame makes the distinction between background and foreground or does it go even deeper

IE: `layer {1..100+}`

I'm sorry if this is a silly question or has been answered I couldn't find it when researching.

#### EDIT

After further review I think I also get that I initialize `SKY` at `(0,0)` which is the top left corner.

Is that what defined this as a background? And `(yellow.x, yellow.y)` is that indicating the position my sprites appear?

Comment: Can you post the variables `PLAYER`, `SIZE`, `MID_BORDER` etc. as well?

Comment: do you mind if I just let you view the code on GitHub? I don't know if I'd give you exactly what you're asking for. https://github.com/AmishMoses/PyGames/blob/main/JetFighter/JetFighterMain.py

Comment: I'm just saying that maybe the coords overlap because of the position of the sprites. We can't run the code if we don't know where the sprites are `blit`.

Comment: Oh my sprites don't overlap I used the MID_BORDER and
```
def main():
    yellow = pygame.Rect(200, 250, 32, 32)
    blue = pygame.Rect(650, 250, 32, 32)
```
to separate the two sprites (not that I fully get that) my big question was how did pygame know what to put as a background and what to put in the foreground.

Comment: D_00 thank you for editing my question and trying to help me. I know it can be aggravating to help someone so new sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pygame draws surfaces in the order you `.blit()` them, so as `SKY` (which is the `bg.png` image) is blit first, it is the background.

Comment: Oh thank you! I couldn't find that in my reading. I'm so new to pygame and all of its quirks. This was my first project and you and a few others have made understanding it a lot easier! I can't upvote your answer because I'm such a noob but really thanks.